# Oracle ROWNUM not coming in expected order

Tags: oracle

I have a procedure that iterates over a cursor and writes SQL out. I want to write a progress counter with the number of rows, so 100, 200, 300, etc.

```
CURSOR c_data IS
SELECT ROWNUM AS rn, <data columns>
FROM <table>
ORDER BY <columns>;

FOR r_data IN c_data LOOP
  <write statement>
  IF MOD(r_data.rn, 100) = 0 THEN
    <write counter>
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

HOWEVER, the output is not in the expected order! It consistently writes out 300, 100, 200, 800, 400, 500, 600, 700.

Any ideas why the ROWNUM is not coming out in order?

***UPDATE:*** It has been pointed out to me that this frequent commit is a terrible idea. I am taking that on board! I'm really out of date and rusty on SQL performance issues. But I'm keeping the progress counter!

Comment: Not directly relevant to the `ROWNUM` issue, but I'd question why you want to commit every 100 rows; that is less performant, and makes it harder to restart after a failure. See [this AskTom article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=performance-and-commits) for example; or [this one])https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022).

Comment: The 100 rows is just my test case, in reality I would set the variable to 10000 or something like that. But I will read those resources and take it on board, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/ROWNUM-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-2E40EC12-3FCF-4A4F-B5F2-6BC669021726):

> For each row returned by a query, the ROWNUM pseudocolumn returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table or set of joined rows.

Crucially this happens before the order-by clause is applied:

> If an ORDER BY clause follows ROWNUM in the same query, then the rows will be reordered by the ORDER BY clause. The results can vary depending on the way the rows are accessed.

So the `rownum` is generated for every row in your result set, and then those are ordered.

You can either use a subquery:

> If you embed the ORDER BY clause in a subquery and place the ROWNUM condition in the top-level query, then you can force the ROWNUM condition to be applied after the ordering of the rows.

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS rn, <data columns>
FROM (
  SELECT <data columns>
  FROM <table>
  ORDER BY <columns>
)
ORDER BY <columns>;
```

or use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <columns>) AS rn, <data columns>
FROM <table>
ORDER BY <columns>;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pqafZ9CD)